# PHP: How to use in_array with an array of regex strings?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an array of paths that consist of regex strings:

```
  $paths = [
    '/cars$',
    '.*\/cars$',
    '^cars\/.*/',
    '/trucks$',
    '.*\/trucks$',
  ];
```

I want to check if my current path matches something in that array, eg:

```
if (in_array($current_path, $paths)) {
  //Do something
}
```

So for example, if my URL is `some-site.com/cars` or `some-site.com/cars/honda` then I want to return something in the if statement.

But I cannot figure out how to get this working with the regex.

I investigated using `preg_grep()` but that seems to only work with one set of regex rules at a time.

I can get this to work with `preg_match` and a string, eg:

```
$paths = '/cars$|.*\/cars$|^cars\/.*/|/trucks$|.*\/trucks$';

if (preg_match($paths, $current_path)) {
  //Do something
}
```

But I will eventually have many URLs added to this list so I would prefer to use an array.

Would anyone know if there is a function that achieves this?

Comment: `foreach` + `break`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know, what patterns of an array match the string, how about using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$res = array_filter($paths, function ($v) USE ($url) {
  return preg_match('~'.$v.'~', $url);
});
```

[See PHP demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aX8jI)

```
echo count($res)." patterns matched:\n"; print_r($res);
```

> 2 patterns matched: Array ( [0] => /cars$ [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) => .*/cars$ )

Used `~` as pattern delimiter, so you wouldn't need to escape all those url slashes.

Be aware, that `.*/cars$` looks redundant, if you already match for `/cars$`.

---

If you want to break on first match, use `foreach` which is probably more efficient ([demo](https://3v4l.org/UO4IN)).

```
foreach($paths AS $v) {
  if (preg_match('~'.$v.'~', $url)) {
    echo $v.' matched'; break;
  }
}
```

You can further easily [display the matched part](https://3v4l.org/B5A98)  of `$url` by using `$out` of `preg_match`.

Comment: This is really weird - I have literally the same code as you (copy, pasted it) but it returns a count of 0 each time. I don't know why.

Comment: @MeltingDog Maybe an old PHP Version? With >= 5.4 it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I could use implode() to return it to a string, eg:

```
$paths = [
    '/cars$',
    '.*\/cars$',
    '^cars\/.*/',
    '/trucks$',
    '.*\/trucks$',
 ];

$paths_string = implode('|', $paths);

if (preg_match($paths_string, $current_path)) {
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: That's really odd... it is working for me. Perhaps there's a different version of PHP. I though '|' was just 'OR'?

Comment: The problem is your regex is missing outer delimiters. You need something like `$paths_string = '#' . implode('|', $paths) . '#';` e.g. https://3v4l.org/0L6kq